# Let me know if I'm reviewing an "answer" or a "question" in all review types

Tags: feature-request, review, wording

In some review queues I know I'm reviewing a Question or Answer because it tells me in big bold letters either:

> **Question**

Or

> **Answer**

While it's fairly obvious once we start to read the post, it would be nice to have it confirmed so I know *what I am beginning to read*, and so know immediately the sorts of review outcomes I will potentially be making.

---

### For example

**Suggested Edits**:

1. I am not shown either "**Question**" or "**Answer**"
2. I know when it's an answer because the title is bold
3. I know when it's a question because the title is *not* bold

But bold/not bold titles is not ideal, I sometimes forget which way it is, and new users won't likely spot that as they're never side-by-side for the difference to be obvious/noticeable.

**First Posts**:

1. When reviewing a *question* I am shown "**Question**"
2. When reviewing an *answer* I am shown "**Answer**"

Simple and ideal.

---

### Proposal

To make it all nice and simple, and not have to remember specific answer and question identification methods in different queues etc, can we have:

In question reviews:
"**Question**"
In Answer reviews:
"**Answer**"

Like "First Posts", and in *all* review queues - even if the review queue type can only have one of "question" or "answer" such as "Late Answers" is only answers but still shows "**Answer**".
Just for continuity throughout and so we can get used to that confirmation text.

Comment: For Suggested Edits in particular it's often pretty crucial. E.g., on SO the injunction against code edits is quite different between the two post types.